# Issue with PSR-0 autoloading

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, psr-0

I am trying to use this composer package with a new project I am working on https://packagist.org/packages/activecollab/activecollab-sdk. However when i try and create a new class I keep getting the following errors.

```
Fatal error: Class 'ActiveCollab\Client' not found
```

The file that is throwing this error looks like this.

```
require "vendor/autoload.php";

new ActiveCollab\Client;
```

Which is just being used to test if the files are being loaded in properly. The composer.json of the file which I am trying to use looks like such. And I have a feeling the problem is in this file but I can't figure out what.

```
stuff...

"autoload": {
      "psr-0": {
        "ActiveCollab\\": "ActiveCollab"
      }
    }

...stuff
```

[image: Folder structure of package]

Also looking at the autload_namespaces.php file it is being generated as such.

```
<?php

// autoload_namespaces.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'ActiveCollab' => array($vendorDir . '/activecollab/activecollab-sdk/ActiveCollab'),
);
```

I have used psr-0 in some composer packages of my own and everything looks to be right except maybe the camel case in the namespace but i don't see this as being disallowed in the php proposal for psr-0.

Thanks for any help this has been driving me crazy.

Comment: I am not certain of this, but according to psr0 doesn't the filename for a class have to be ClassName.php. So using ClassName.class.php might violate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is: You cannot simply add a `composer.json` file with a random autoloading configuration and hope that it works - it actually has to match the naming scheme you are using. That is what this project got wrong, and nobody tested it. Which probably means nobody uses this library, and you can expect no support from the creators due to lack of interest.

But let's see how they react on [my pull request](https://github.com/activecollab/activecollab-sdk/pull/6) to get things back to working again.

Comment: Awesome, Thank you so much. I tried to do what you did but I had a bit of misunderstanding of the psr-0 standard which looking over your code has cleared up for me.

Comment: The maintainer reacted pretty quickly to the issue and fixed the problem with tagged version 1.0.3. You should simply update and be done.

Comment: For anyone else looking at this. on top of the changes Sven made the also had the path wrong in the composer.json file it was set as "ActiveCollab": "ActiveCollab" which i believe does not satisfy the naming conventions when mapping since you would no longer include the Package Name in the use statement. Instead switching it to "ActiveCollab": "/" and everything worked as expected. Thanks again for all the help Sven.

Comment: You are right, I should have probably changed the autoloading scheme to be PSR-4 instead. Actually, I got my other pull request merged with used the classmap scheme, and then the developer decided to go the renaming route. Shame on me for not having tested it - even the 5-minute-fix is bad if it doesn't fix it.

Comment: Yeah I am not sure if that developer have used composer before but I am glad he is taking pull requests to support it. Hopefully the docs I added will help with it not getting broken again.

Answer (score 0):

The composer config looks fine: Is it just the case that you omitted the leading \ from your class name?

```
new \ActiveCollab\Client;
```

You'll need that if your code is inside another namespace, as it will load it relative to the current namespace.

EDIT: I've just checked out that library, and even with the above fix, the autoloader wasn't quite working.  The autoloader may also be broken due to the `composer.json` file for the library  specifying a PSR0 autoloader, but using ".class.php" extensions (not PSR0 compatible).  An autoload.php file is included with the library, so if you just `require` that file, you should be able to use the classes:

`require 'vendor/activecollab/activecollab-sdk/ActiveCollab/autoload.php';`

After doing this, I was able to use the class.